# How to find if the processor has hardfloat

Tags: cpu

My mobile got `MSM8953`, App, `Droid info` says:

```
Instruction Sets: armeabi-v7a, aremeabi
CPU Features: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 sha3 crc32
```

How to say it got `hardfloat` or not?

Comment: `vfp`, `vfpv3`, `vfpv4`, `vfpd32` all say it has hardware support for floating-point: https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/floating-point. Btw, MSM8953 has 64-bit CPU architecture (`ARMv8-A`), not 32-bit (`ARMv7-A`): https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-625-mobile-platform

Comment: So the tuple that describes the processor build system should be `armv7a-unknown-linux-musleabi` or `armv7a-unknown-linux-musleabihf`?

Comment: Firstly, that question cannot be answered without getting further information. Secondly, development related questions are dealt at https://stackoverflow.com/. This site is meant for end users.

Comment: OK, I'll ask at stackoverflow.com